# Solution of ODE given in terms of functions in $x$ and $y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying Ordinary Differential Equations and I came across a question where we are asked to solve an ODE which is given in terms of some functions $r_1(x,y)$ and $r_2(x,y)$. I am not getting the idea of how to solve it. The ODE is:
$$y' = \dfrac y {x+\dfrac {r_2^3 - r_1^3}{r_2^3 + r_1^3}}$$ where $r_2(x,y)$ and $r_1(x,y)$ are some functions in $x$ and $y$.
$$r_1(x,y)=\sqrt {(x+1)^2+y^2}$$
$$r_2(x,y)=\sqrt {(x-1)^2+y^2}$$

I tried to solve it by substituting $x=r\cos θ$ and $y=r\sin θ$ but that too didn't work. Can anybody please help me solve this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am also attaching the image of the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A26IG.png)

Comment: Do you really have there a fraction of a fraction? Better: please read the directions on how to properly write mathematics in this site.

Comment: I have attached image also.

Comment: forget it. There is no analytical solution.

Comment: It looks like $y(x) = (\pm 1 \pm' i) x$ are solutions, subject to the usual caution about branch cuts of complex functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to contribute some visualizations about the problem.
But in fact have no idea how to solve this ODE analytically.

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x+\frac{r_2(x,y)^3-r_1(x,y)^3}{r_2(x,y)^3+r_1(x,y)^3}}$ with $r_1(x,y)=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$ and $r_2(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

Show function $f(x,y)$:

[image]

Next a direction field plot (slope field) of the ODE $y'=f(x,y)$:

[image]

Finally a stream plot of the ODE, which shows some possible solution trajectories:

[image]

I hope the problem has become at least a little clearer.
May be other users can better illuminate the problem.